# Python: continue on with the loop after an error occurs

Tags: python

So, I'm doing this assignment and I can't seem to figure out how to continue on to the next step.
[assignment output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyWBC.png)

The file numbers.txt contains the following numbers all on separate lines (25, 15, 5, six, 35, one, 40).

My problem is that I can only print out one ValueError message (six), but I need to be able to print out both messages (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'six\n', invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'one\n').

Since I can't get the codes to move on to the next iteration, my average only adds 25, 15, and 5.
I've only been learning Python for a month so I don't know if there's a simple way to solve all these problems.

Below is the code I am working on.

```
def main():

while True:
    try:
        filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
        infile = open(filename, "r")

    except IOError:
        print("[Error No. 2] No such file or directory:", filename)
        continue # continue to next iteration

    else:
        break

data = infile.readline().strip()
numbers = data.split()
total = 0
count = 0
try:
    infile = open(filename, "r") #somehow without this, the first line won't print
    for line in infile:
        num = int(line)
        print(num)
        total += num
        count += 1
    print("The average is: ", total/count)

except ValueError as err:
    print(err)
finally:

    print(total/count)

main()
```

Comment: do you need to convert `six` and `one` to numbers? Please explain what do you want to do with them.

Comment: you can check if file exists using `os` module, then you also don't need that `try/except`

Answer (score 1):

You can repositioning your `try` statement in the second loop like so:

```
data = infile.readline().strip()
numbers = data.split()
total = 0
count = 0
infile = open(filename, "r") 
for line in infile:
    try:
        num = int(line)
        print(num)
        total += num
        count += 1
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
print("The average is: ", total/count)
```

This way, you won't exit the loop once you encounter an error message, and will simply print it and move on to the next line.

Comment: Ah, I knew I had all the right ingredients. This makes so much sense. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help, if this answers your question please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
# open the file using 'with' - it will make sure that the file will be closed
with open('input.txt') as f:
    values = []
    # read the lines into a list
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        # try to convert to int
        try:
            x = int(line)
            values.append(x)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
    # calculate the average 
    print(f'Avg: {sum(values)/len(values)}')
```

input.txt

```
25
15
5
six
35
one
40
```

output

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'six'
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'one'
Avg: 24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your while True as currently the main function is causing an error.
You should also do an if line == ‘six’:
line  = 6

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `try-except` block inside the for loop which should produce the correct results.

```
data = infile.readline().strip()
numbers = data.split()
total = 0
count = 0

infile = open(filename, "r") 
for line in infile:
    try:
        num = int(line)
        total += num
        count += 1
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
print("The average is: ", total/count)
```